# Can't Update Record to Sql Server Database Using Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have problems regarding updating my records in a SQL Server database using stored procedure in C#.

I have a stored procedure named `Outfin` for recording the time out of an employee and this is how it is coded:

```
create procedure dbo.Outfin
(
   @EmpRec int,
   @Time varchar(11)
)
as begin
    Update EmpRec 
    set Outfin = @Time 
    where EmpRec = @EmpRec
end
```

And this is how I implement this in my program:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(scmd, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpRec", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Recordholder;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label6.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`label6.Text` there is `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()` giving me a value of `hh:mm:ss AM`

ALSO this code will only implement if the `System.DateTime.Now` is >5:30:00 PM and <12:00:00 AM. I can't see anything wrong with the code but it won't update anything in the database. `Recordholder` holds the `EmpRec` when I fetch the record before this code runs.

Help me out guys! Thanks! Have a good day!

Comment: So, no error it just does not change anything in the database? Have you trued - ah - cough - attaching a debugger, seeing whether the sql that is emitted makes sense and running it in the sql studio? If there is no error and the variables are ok, you can safely remove the C# and say you need help with basic sql.

Answer (score 0):

what is Recordholder here ??

also change your code behind to use command parameters like this.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(scmd, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpRec", Recordholder);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", label6.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```